# Build network based on shortest distance between points

Tags: qgis, point, distance, network

Is there a way to build a network based on the shortest distances between each point of a point layer.

I have occurrence data from species (as points) and want to estimate whether there are one or more populations. As I know (more or less) the potential dispersal ability of the species I can estimate whether the occurrence points could be connected populations or whether they are isolated from each other.